# jQuery / HTML / CSS colspan issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

first question so take it easy.

I have a problem with the JSFiddle referenced below.  It involves the interaction of jQuery with HTML tables and CSS.

I have 'header' class rows that are the only rows displayed on page load.

On click, the jQuery toggles the visibility of the next items until the next 'header' class object is found.

The issue is that seems to change the colspan settings and the data is only shown in the first column.

If you remove the first 7 lines of CSS, you will see that it initially loads correctly where the data spans across all columns.

I've only worked with the stuff for about a month so it's all rather new...and probably is a mixture of bad coding and stupidity.

HTML:

```
<div class="datagrid">
<table align="center">
    <tr class ="header">
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Useremail@domain.com</th>
        <th><span>+</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <ul>
        <li>4G Account</li>
        <li>3G Account</li>
        <li>2G Account</li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class ="header">
        <th>User1</th>
        <th>Useremail1@domain.com</th>
        <th><span>+</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <ul>
        <li>4G Account</li>
        <li>3G Account</li>
        <li>2G Account</li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  tr {
    display: none;
}

tr.header {
    display: table-row;
}
.datagrid table th {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #8C8C8C), color-stop(1, #7D7D7D) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #8C8C8C 5%, #7D7D7D 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8C8C8C', endColorstr='#7D7D7D');
    background-color:#8C8C8C;
    color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px; 
    font-weight: bold; border-left: 1px solid #A3A3A3; }
```

jQuery:

```
var $headers = $('.header').click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
        return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
    });

    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header')
    .attr('colspan', 2)
    .slideToggle(100, function () {})

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teHWF/97/

Comment: You're setting a `colspan` on the `<tr>`, but `colspan` can only be set on `<td>` elements.

Comment: You are using tables wrong (they are for tabular data only) and the fiddle works as expected.  The reason why the data is shown in one column is because you have only created one column and put a list into it

Comment: Good point doctororange, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: if you are wanting the ul (list) placed in columns - try this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/teHWF/110/, if you want to stop the columns moving when they open you will need to assign them fixed widths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

You're setting a `colspan` on the `<tr>`, but the `colspan` attribute can only be set on `<td>` elements. Also, I'm not sure what is intended to be achieved by setting it to `2`. This may be unnecessary?

Also, jQuery's `slideToggle` is setting the css `display` property of the `<tr>` to `block` when showing it, when you really want it to be `table-row`.

Here's a fiddle which fixes that problem by toggling classes instead: http://jsfiddle.net/jCW6B/

The animation of `slideToggle` wasn't working anyway, since setting the `height` of the table row (which is what `slideToggle` does under the hood) is inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution. I will now examine all the points you've made - this is really helpful information. Thanks again. :) Karl

Comment: No problem. As @Pete suggested, depending on what your final application is here, tables may not be the most suitable container to use here anyway. They're not the easiest to work with if you want to use jQuery's built in animations.

Answer (score 0):

About a year ago, I too was in "table mode"...but after a time you get better at using divs, and using tables only for tabular data (I've learned tons from the experts here on SO).

So for the fun of it, I redid your concepts in all divs - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/teHWF/112/).

JS

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $(this).children('.accounts').toggle();
});
```

There are thousands of ways to do this type of stuff, I've given you a brute-force, inelegant method, but perhaps it's something to think about.